# Need help with error after upgrade to EE v6

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades, php-errors, ee6

Just upgraded EE from V2 to 6.3.2 and all fine except this error when trying to edit entries:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in xxxx/xxx/xxxx/ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/pages/tab.pages.php on line 130
```

Anyone got any idea on cause or possible fix?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like this is an error with some of the code in PHP 5.6  If possible to upgrade to PHP 7.x or higher, this should be resolved.

We'll also make a change to fix this in PHP 5.6 in the core.